# FCIFlushCabinet throws Access Violation Error with Cabinet.lib but worked with FCI.Lib and Fdi.Lib

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

We had a visual studio 6.0 project, where we used...
FCI.LIB
FDI.LIB
and the APIs 
       FCICreate, FCIAddFile, and FCIFlushCabinet.

it worked good. But as switched to VS2015, we had to replace FCI.LIB and FDI.LIB with Cabinet.Lib.

It builds fine and executes till FCICreate and FCIAddFile. 
But FCIFlushCabinet() throws the below runtime error.
Exception thrown at 0x5DCADE7E (vcruntime140.dll) in CabProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x57EC8B55.

Please suggest, what's wrong over here.

Comment: Hi user3506849, check all input parameters of FCIFlushCabinet() function to see if they are all valid value. Please show a mini sample code that can reproduce this issue. It will be more useful for others help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot @RitaHan-MSFT. The original second parameter value was 'FALSE'. Now changed to 'TRUE' and generates the CAB file and I am able to open that via WinRar. However, I am Not clear - why the 'FALSE' throwing the access violation.  BOOL ret = FCIFlushCabinet(m_hfci,
          TRUE,
          get_next_cabinet,
          progress);

Comment: [If fGetNextCab is set TRUE, GetNextCab is called to obtain continuation information. If FALSE, then GetNextCab is called only in the event the cabinet overflows.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fci/nf-fci-fciflushcabinet#remarks). [The callback function indicated by GetNextCab will be called if the cabinet overflows, which occurs if the pending data buffered inside an FCI causes the application-specified cabinet media size to be exceeded.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fci/nf-fci-fciflushfolder#remarks).

Comment: Is there an overflow?

Comment: It was hardly 200Kbs. So, less chance of overflowing... Here's the CCB params lMaxSize is 128 MB.
 m_cabParams.cb = lMaxSize;
 m_cabParams.cbFolderThresh = FOLDER_THRESHOLD;
 m_cabParams.cbReserveCFData   = 0;
 m_cabParams.cbReserveCFFolder = 0;
 m_cabParams.cbReserveCFHeader = 0;
 m_cabParams.iCab = 1;
 m_cabParams.iDisk = 0;

Comment: I am trying to comment out all the values for the CCB to keep it default and put values only essential field like CCB.szCabPath, CCB.szCab and CCB.lMaxSize. And test again.

Comment: Looks the Max value of 'cbFolderThresh' is 312617. We had given with old version was '900000'. Finally, it's resolved. Thanks a lot for your guidance!

Comment: You're welcome. You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Provide an answer and it will be helpful  for others searching on the same issue in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, follow Rita Han's helpful comments.
Even after setting 312617 as value of m_cabParams.cbFolderThresh was overflowing with someother file.

Later it's changed 1024 * 128 = 131072. Further, it was failing with a particular XML file compression.

Then, found we have a call back function "FNFCISTATUS" and there some unnecessary manipulation is done. Commenting out that code helped to resolve the issue.

```
FNFCISTATUS(progress)
{

client_state    *cs;

cs = (client_state *) pv;

if (typeStatus == statusFile)
{
    /*
    cs->total_compressed_size += cb1;
    cs->total_uncompressed_size += cb2;
    */
```